# Is this an equivalent definition of cluster point?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

My textbook **Analysis I** by Amann/Escher defines the notions of *neighborhood* and *cluster point* as follows:

> [image]
>   [image]

Then the authors present equivalent definitions of cluster point:

> [image]

---

I would like to ask if the below definition of cluster point is equivalent to the one given in my textbook?

> $a \in X$ is a cluster point of $(x_{n})$ if, for each $U \in \mathcal{U}(a)$, there is some $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_m \in U$ and $x_m \neq a$.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $x_n=a$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, any neighbourhood of $a$ contains every element of the sequence, and so, in particular, infinitely many terms. As such, $a$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

In general, we want it to be true that if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent, then it has a unique cluster point: The limit.